verbose_query_logs does not work for queries issued in spec
In test.rb I have
config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

and queries issued in a Rails request show the ↳ lines, but queries issued in specs do not. I want to know where a DELETE is issued during spec preparation.
  Article Load (0.2ms) SELECT "articles". * FROM "articles".
  ↳ app/models/article.rb:5 # <- this

Is there any way to display this?
Rails 7.0.4 + FactoryBot 6.4.6 + rspec 3.13.0

What is the config.log_level = in your test.rb file?

config.log_level = :debug
